# How to serve multiple web sites by the one ADFS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, saml, adfs, ws-federation

I have two servers: one of them serves UI (it is called webUI) and another works with data (it is called webAPI).

I try to implement an authentication across the ADFS server. It has *Relying Party Trusts* for both servers: [urn=webui,identifier=address/webui],[urn=webapi,identifier=address/webapi].

I adjused the HttpConfiguration for webUI and user can be authenticated and use website, which the webUI serves (it's good).

```
        var wsFedMetAdd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFedMetAdd"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wsFedMetAdd))
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(Properties.Resources.InvalidMetadataAddress);

        var wsFedWtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFedWtrealm"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wsFedWtrealm))
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(Properties.Resources.InvalidWtrealm);

        appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        });

        var options = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = wsFedMetAdd,
            Wtrealm = wsFedWtrealm,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Federation"
        };
        appBuilder.UseWsFederationAuthentication(options);

        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Admin" });
```

Once client gets RequestSecurityTokenResponse (SAML Token). Also responses from ADFS set cookies for further requests (MSISAuth, MSISAuthenticated and so on).

The webAPI has the same implemention of HttpConfiguration (only one difference - wsFedWtrealm is *urn:webapi* instead *urn:webui*). Then I try send a request to the webAPI from client and the ADFS Server asks to authenticate one more.

I can't understand what should I do to use the same credentials for webAPI which I entered for webUI. Or maybe I should use SAML Token?

---

UPDATE

Wow. It is worked without SAML token, just using cookies.
When the user tries to be authenticated for webUI, diverse cookies are set on client (.AspNet.Federation, MSISAuth, MSISAuthenticated...). Then I substitute the webUI link with the webAPI link in the address bar and then webAPI doesn't ask to enter login and password. Hence data is displayed in browser. Authentication is picked up for webUI and for webAPI too.

But now problem is I get the error when javascript tries to send a request to webAPI:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   *https://my_address/adfs/ls/?wtrealm=urn%3awebapi&wctx=_* No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://my_address:9001' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: You can add a custom `IHttpModule` to send the header.  See: http://charliedigital.com/2015/07/17/adventures-in-single-sign-on-cross-domain-script-request/

Comment: @CharlesChen thank you! You can observe my answer below which has the link to the same post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](http://charliedigital.com/2015/07/17/adventures-in-single-sign-on-cross-domain-script-request/) help me to solve my problem.

I added to code of index.html new element iframe. Attribute *src* is the link to my webAPI.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ADFS?

You are mixing two protocols - Web API generally uses OAuth.

Use OpenID Connect for the UI and then that will naturally flow into the WebAPI as per this : [Securing a Web API with ADFS on WS2012 R2 Got Even Easier](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

Or for a somewhat more convoluted approach - [what protocol to use with ADFS when security webapi for non-browser clients](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29593077/9922)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. In fact I don't want to mix protocols. And maybe I don't want to use the convoluted approach. Yet. Now I just want to know, is it possible to use the SAML token which client gets from webUI with webAPI? My thoughts about this are I use webUI, webUI authenticates me through the ADFS server and the ADFS server assignes token to me.Then this token is returned to client.And then I want to send this token to webAPI and it understands that this token is valid for me as user of ADFS Server.

Comment: The problem is that Web API uses a JSON token whereas WS-Fed uses a SAML token. So you would lean towards WCF.

Comment: hmm.. my knowledge in Web API is not so deep. and I doubt about your comment "Web API uses a JSON token". because I may point what I will use for my server: JSON Token or OpenID or ws-federation. this is just protocol. if I'm not right, correct me, please. also you can provide link to read about. I'll be very grateful. and I figured out how to solve my problem =) thank you a lot!

Comment: The token type is tied to the protocol - OpenID Connect is JSON, WS Fed is SAML XML etc.