# How to configure/extend the SelfHost (InMem with WS-Fed) sample

Tags: identityserver3

I'd like to configure(if possible) or extend the sample to have an endpoint/route to exchange user credentials (userName+pwd, the same credentials provided through the current built-in login sampkle page) with a SecurityToken (along with all other current validation such as Wtrealm, relying-party, etc.).

My goal is to use the WS-Fed for the authentication part of the OAuth2 Authorization Grants(implemented w/ a different library - DNOA). I could use current "SelfHost (InMem with WS-Fed)" sample to support "AuthorizationCode Grant" and "Implicit Grant", but in order to support "ROPC Grant" as well I need some equivalent api on the authentication provider as well.

EDITED

We already have an OAuth2 STS built w/ DNOA that also take care of the user authentication(accessing directly the user storage).
Our next step is decouple the authentication from the authorization (same as [this example using OpenID](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/develop/samples/OAuthAuthorizationServer/Controllers/AccountController.cs))  to an external federated provider (ADFS or equivalent) that's why I'm looking at IdentiyServerWS-Fed.

I'd like to extend the sample to obtain directly a set of user cliams in exchange of the user credentials within the request (see: "[For the client to request the saml 2.0 token from ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593077/what-protocol-to-use-with-adfs-when-security-webapi-for-non-browser-clients/29685471#29685471)")

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer supports the OAuth 2.0 resource owner password flow out of the box. Use the `password` grant type for that:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/token.html

You need to implement the IUserService interface (especially the `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method) to validate the incoming credentials.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm aware about the OAuth2 support in IdentityServer, but we already have our OAuth2 sts, we just want to decouple it from the authentication, that should be delegated to a federated authentication provider (see EDITED question for more details)